# How to have Simultaneous Dial within Conference using TwiML

Tags: c#, twilio

Scenario: Call is received and caller is placed in a conference using the following code

```
var response = new TwilioResponse();
response
  .Say("Please wait while we attempt to locate the person you were trying to reach.")
  .DialConference(string.Format("{0} Waiting Room", digits), new { beep = "false"})
return TwiML(response);
```

Now I need to Dial out and connect to a mobile users phone and prompt them to accept or send caller to voice mail. I'm assuming once the DialConference is initiate the original caller is placed on hold and no more TwiML is processed. So the only way to initiate a new call is to use the RestAPI.

However I would like to use the .net helper's fluent syntax and it "should" be possible. If you know an example of doing a simultaneous Dial using the fluent syntax, it should also work with the Conference verb.

How do I initiate an outbound call while having a received call put into a conference room, all using TwiML?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

There isn't a way using only TwiML to put Caller A into the conference, then dial Caller B.  With your example above, Twilio will stop executing the TwiML once it hits the Dial and not start again until Caller A leaves the conference.

However, if you just want call screening, then you could check out this HowTo, which shows you how without the conference:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callscreening

Hope that helps.

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation on handling this with just TwiML. What I'm trying to do is allow the Caller B to listen to Caller A's name after recording and choose to accept or reject call.

Comment: Sure.  If thats he case you can use the above HowTo as a starting point.  You would just need to use the Record verb to record Caller A saying their name and then grab the Recording URL and store somewhere (app state, database etc).

Once you have the recording URL, you can Play that to caller B when you make the outbound call to them.